# SystemD running script before device driver loaded

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero, boot-issues, systemd

We've a few Pi's, model 2, 3B+ and Zero W all running default Raspbian and with the latest firmware updates as of 25 March '19. All of these have an Infineon TPM 2.0 board attached to the gpio pins configured to use SPI. Config.txt is configured with the loading of the correct overlay and the SPI bus on.

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=tpm-slb9670
```

On boot we have a script run by systemd to write some data into the TPM. We are using the the Infineon eltt2 tool to access the TPM (we also use Intel's TPM2 tools also, but during boot only eltt2 is used).

On the zero w only, during boot systemd reports that the script fails ( error 2 - invalid argument). We've traced this down to the TPM not being accessible. Using dmesg we get the following:

```
$dmesg | grep tpm
[ 5.338101] systemd[1]: [/etc/systemd/system/tpm2_measure_eltt2.service:12] Unknown lvalue 'After' in section 'Install'
[ 29.151117] tpm_tis_spi spi0.1: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0x1B, rev-id 16)
```

Ignore the error from systemd, it was only because of this error that we discovered that systemd is trying to run the script before the tpm device driver gets loaded by the kernel.

So basically what seems to be happening is that the TPM device driver doesn't get started until much later in the boot sequence (and thus does not send the startup command to the TPM). After login the script to access the TPM runs perfectly.

Any help appreciated at this stage. Note, this affects the zero w only.

Comment: you possibly need to change the `after` or `requires` (assuming you've created a systemd service) - with so little *actual* information about the "script" you "have", it's hard to say

Comment: The systemd script is little more than which bash script to execute and the WantedBy statement which works fine on the other models. The script referred to by the ExecStart is a simple bash script containing an instruction to write to one of the TPM's PCR registers using the (Infineon) eltt2 command. There's nothing more than that really, other than the configuration in config.txt. As I said, this works on the other PI models but not the Zero which is where I'm wondering what is actually happening here.

Comment: pi2 and 3b+ are faster, so perhaps the timing is fortuitous with them - I dont' suppose there's any unit/service you can "requires" in your service is there?

Comment: or maybe your script can wait until `/dev/tpm0` exists before continuing

Comment: waiting for a device to exist can be achieved in systemd too ... https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2012-January/160917.html - oops, never mind, that's for USB device

Comment: Seems to be a timing/ordering question,  One solution is to add sleep 30 to the script. The device /dev/tpm0 is available, but the driver is required to send a startup command to the device - this is the part that is not happening until much later in the boot sequence it seems.  I found a link to the udev solution (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186899/how-to-wait-for-a-dev-video0-before-starting-a-service) - same as your suggestion. This unfortunately did not work.

Comment: Just noticed a subtle difference in the Fedora answer ... systemd script using Wants instead of BindsTo  ... that latter one caused all sorts of problems.

Comment: As I said, Udev is for usb devices

Comment: What you may want to look at is "Systemd Path Unit" - I assume once `/dev/tmp0` exists, all is ready to go - the "PathExists" demo at https://blog.andrewkeech.com/posts/170809_path.html could be what you're looking for

Comment: You cannot "*Ignore the error from systemd*". It is a syntax error. There is no option **After** defined for section `[Install]`. Please edit your question and and paste the output of this command to it: `systemctl cat tpm2_measure_eltt2.service`. Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: HI @Ingo I'm not ignoring the error from systemd, it was because I introduced that error that I found the ordering error in the output of dmesg; I now know it is a syntax error. I'm currently writing up the solution to this which involves adding a rule to udev that forces the systemd script to wait for the device to become ready. Will need to do a bit of testing tomorrow, but so far so good.

Comment: You don't like to give more information? I'm not sure if you really need an udev rule to wait for the device to become ready. There are many dependencies you can simply use.